# Keyboard shortcut switch to space

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, spaces, fullscreen

I just found out about the ^1, ^2 etc. keyboard shortcuts for switching to desktops.

[image]

Those *only* do desktops though.

How can I set-up keyboard shortcuts to switch to spaces?

E.g. full-screen safari is space 1, desktop is space 2, safari's fullscreen video that's being played is space 3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is one of those features that was just really badly thought-through from the outset, when the new fullscreen paradigm was added, & hasn't been fixed yet.

- You can only use key commands to go directly to numbered Spaces.
- Fullscreen Spaces don't have a number.
- Catch 22

Best you can do is use the number keys to get to the last numbered Space, then  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>  to get to the fullscreen Space you require.

Yet another reason I never use fullscreen.

BTW, according to your Shortcuts picture, you only have one Space set up. The  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[num]</kbd>  shortcuts are added automatically [but not activated by default] as you add each potential Space.

[image]

Compared to my 7...

[image]

Safari full-screened to the right, as an example. Spaces have numbers, fullscreens have names.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean I have only one space set-up? I have three....?

Comment: Added pictures to my answer. You have one shortcut, so you have one Space. Anything with a name is fullscreen, not a Space. Spaces only have numbers.

Comment: Oh. I've been using wrong terminology. I'd always distinguished between spaces and desktops. Apparently a space _is_ a desktop? And thus fullscreen apps aren't in their own spaces?

Comment: tbh, the terminologies appear to be pretty much interchangeable. In Mission Control Apple refers to all as Spaces, in Shortcuts they're all Desktops. Maybe a fullscreen app is just outside the definition altogether - as it a) has no desktop behind it & b) has no Space number.

Comment: What's a space number?

Comment: Desktop/Space... interchangeable...